# Service Unavailable on Microsoft edge using windows 10

Tags: localhost, iis-6, iis-express

The dos command **ping localhost** works. But accessing localhost using either Chrome/Edge browser throwing error Service Unavailable. From past 3 hours I am troubleshooting with no success.
Note: Under development application is not tested on any other browser.

Comment: Can you add screenshot with your LAN Settings and/or Proxy Settings? What are you even trying to connect to? A specific service with a specific port? Just an IIS Website? 
More details are appreciated to help you.

Comment: @Lukas, Specific to connect to IIS Website. I am working on a standalone computer. Computers are not connected in LAN. Hope this gives required information.

Comment: not really, you didnt show any of your information. If you want to connect to an internal IIS website, you have to configure it correctly. If you dont give these info, no one will be able to check if there is something wrong about you config, thus your problem couldnt be solved.

Comment: Please learn the differences between ping/ICMP and web browsing/HTTP. The protocols are irrelevant. Tell us more about this machine (what you installed/configured), so that we might tell what happened. Service Unavailable indicates disabled application pool on IIS, but too early to draw any conclusion.

Comment: @Lex Li 6, Thanks for your response. Sure I need to learn about ICMP and HTTP (Protocol). What I understand is running ping command verifies that the website is up and running. no issue with website. correct me if wrong. Also I have done hands-on with IIS 5.0 and pervious versions. Versions further to IIS 6.0 I have never done hand-on so I am not daring to go in depth. I cannot take chance (take risks) even playing on local.  As the work i am pursuing is OFFICIAL. I need to consider lot of limitations before I proceed. Hope I made you understand.

Comment: No. If you dig deeper into ICMP you will see "running ping command verifies that the website is up and running" is not true (an IIS server can even refuse ICMP requests while serving HTTP requests). Experience with IIS 5 and lower is far from enough. IIS 6 and above introduced too many key changes (starting with application pools), so you do need to refresh your knowledge before moving on.

Comment: @Lex Li, Really a thankful information.